# mvn compiler:compile works, mvn compile not

Tags: maven

I have a project with a maven pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Minimal-J</groupId>
    <artifactId>Minimal-J</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Minimal-J</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.8.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
            <version>10.8.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
            <version>6.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.miglayout</groupId>
            <artifactId>miglayout</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

if I execute

> mvn compiler:compile

all 189 of my java classes are compiled

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Minimal-J 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.4:compile (default-cli) @ Minimal-J ---
[INFO] Compiling 189 source files to C:\projects\open-ech\workspace\minimal-j\MinimalJ\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.386s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri May 11 11:50:54 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/37M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

if I simply type

> mvn compile

Nothing seems to be done:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Minimal-J 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.120s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri May 11 11:53:36 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 1M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In a other project everything works fine.

Where could I possibly have configured something wrong to trigger this behaviour?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because of `pom` packaging. By invoking `mvn compiler:compile` you run `compile` goal outside Maven's default lifecycle and that basically compile sources in `src/main/java`. And by `mvn compile` you run lifecycle up to `compile` phase and the actual goals executed in every single phase depend on project's packaging type then. `pom`-type project does nothing in `compile` phase, because - in fact - there is nothing to compile with just POM.

I suppose your intention was to have `jar` packaging and changing that should help.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've removed the packaging and everything works. The pom.xml was generated by eclipse, maybe there it has to be included. And I unterstand the tricky difference between compiler:compile and compile a little bit better now.